# Rewrite URL IIS Https rule breaks after adding new rule for JavaScript Versioning

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, web-config

I had a rule Http to Https redirect which was working fine.

But now I am adding new rule in the same  tag for IIS rewrite rule to add query string to .js references in the entire MVC website pages.
Now what happens is that the previous rule which was applied is also not working after adding the new rule as well as new rule also does not work.

Below is the rule from HTTP to Https redirect and this code works fine.

```
    <location path="." allowOverride="true" inheritInChildApplications="false">
        <system.webServer>
            <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="httpsRedirect" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)"/>
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$"/>
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}
                                                {REQUEST_URI}"/>         
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
    </location>
```

What I am doing wrong in the below code? Please suggest.

```
<location path="." allowOverride="true" inheritInChildApplications="false">
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="httpsRedirect" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)"/>
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$"/>
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}"/>
            </rule>
            <rule name="JSVersioning" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*).js" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                     <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" />
                     <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="version=3911" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}.js?version=3911" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: You can help yourself by seeing into FRT, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: Did you get any error messages? or have you modified any settings? Usually subsequent rules will not affect previous rules, or you can use failed request tracking to view detailed error information, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.